# The background size of a span element

Tags: css

I have a span element and I gave it a background-color, is there is any way to control this particular background-size?

I tried `background-size: auto 2px; (2px for example)` but it had no effects on it, what I want from the background color is to be a little bit smaller -height wise-, I want it to be from the top edge of the number to the bottom edge of it only, not bigger, is it possible?

```css
button {
    background-color: rgb(41, 184, 250);
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 1em;
    transition: button 20ms ease;
}
span {
    background-color: white;
    background-size: auto 2px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Unread Messages
        <span>9</span>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

background-size apply to only image so make your color an image using gradient:

```css
button {
  background-color: rgb(41, 184, 250);
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 1em;
  transition: button 20ms ease;
}

span {
  background: linear-gradient(white 0 0);
  background-size: auto 10px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Unread Messages
        <span>9</span>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `display:inline-block;` and set the width you want.

```css
button {
    background-color: rgb(41, 184, 250);
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 1em;
    transition: button 20ms ease;
}
span {
    background-color: white;
    width:20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">Unread Messages
        <span>9</span>
    </button>
```